# C# Assign a subclass of a property type to the property?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I did over an hour of searching on StackOverflow and elsewhere, and could not find an answer to this exact question.

In Unity 2020.1, I have a State() class with a StateLogic property. There are several subclasses of StateLogic to handle the game logic for different states, such as IdleStateLogic and MoveToStateLogic. The idea is that State() itself is generalized, and different scriptable objects for game logic, sensing, and transitions can be added in the inspector (this is heavily based on the "Pluggable AI" architecture).

However, the StateLogic property is unique in that it needs to be able to be assigned subclasses of StateLogic(). However, currently subclassed StateLogic() classes cannot be assigned to the property:

```
public class State : ScriptableObject
{
    [field: SerializeField]
    public virtual StateLogic stateLogic { get; set; }

    ...
```

The StateLogic() base class is defined with `public abstract class StateLogic : ScriptableObject`. And its subclass IdleStateLogic() is defined with `public class IdleStateLogic : StateLogic`.

How do I modify the StateLogic property on State(), such that I can assign a StateLogic() subclass to it like IdleStateLogic()?

EDIT:

Here is the simplest possible minimal reproducible example I could make:

The StateController has a currentState:

```
public class StateController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public State currentState;
}
```

The currentState State is a ScriptableObject that hold references to its game logic StateLogic, its Actions, and its Transitions (all of these are separate classes):

```
public class State : ScriptableObject
{
    [field: SerializeField]
    public virtual StateLogic stateLogic { get; set; }
    public Action[] actions;
    public Transition[] transitions;
}
```

The stateLogic property is visible in the inspector, but nothing can be assigned to it. The goal is to be able to assign subclasses of StateLogic to the stateLogic property of State in the inspector. Subclasses like IdleStateLogic:

```
public class IdleStateLogic : StateLogic
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Note that we're taking UnitStateController instead of the base class' StateController, so this is not
    /// an override method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="c"></param>
    public void Enter(UnitStateController c)
    {
        Debug.Log("Enter IdleStateLogic");
    }
}
```

So the question is, why can't I assign anything to the stateLogic property in the inspector? Shouldn't IU be able to drag and drop a subclass of StateLogic to that property? The problem persists when stateLogic is declared instead as `public StateLogic stateLogic;`

I simply don't understand why it can't be assigned to.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of this. What you described should work as-is.

Comment: *Side note: don't put `()` after class names, only method names, and even there it's not really necessary.*

Comment: Ah, ok I wanted to differentiate between the StateLogic property and class. Since this system is modular, there are 8 or 9 scripts involved here. I don't want to overcomplicate it, since the question is just about this one property. I'll get to work now on creating a new/different minimal reproducible example based on the link you provided. Thanks!

Comment: The property and the class are already different because you've used different case for each, `StateLogic` vs. `stateLogic`.

Comment: C# conventions are that properties would also use PascalCase, but Unity tends to dispense with that. When you really need to differentiate them and case is the same, say "the `StateLogic` class" or "the `StateLogic` property", and it doesn't hurt to do that even when they *are* different. Typing more is not a bad thing if it adds clarity.

Comment: @madreflection excellent points, thank you for the advice. I'll be sure to use parentheticals less after class names when writing/asking about them. I have made a minimal reproducible example as an edit to my post, per your request. Please let me know what you think! Thanks again.

Comment: `[SerializeField]` doesn't work for properties .. only for fields. Why does it need to be `virtual`? Did you try to remove these `{get; set;}` and make it not `virtual` ? If you still need a virtual property you should exose a backing field in the Inspector and then have an additional public virtual property for stuff doing via code ...

Comment: @derHugo: It has the `field:` prefix. That was added for auto-implemented properties in C# 7.3.

Comment: @derHugo If I change the stateLogic property to how it was originally defined, ```public StateLogic stateLogic;``` the result is exactly the same. I still cannot assign IdleStateLogic to it, even though its a subclass of StateLogic.

Comment: @Sciguy77: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Rg4yo ... What you described works. But there are some other things in your design that aren't going to work such as the non-virtual would-be-contravariant `Enter` method. I tweaked it accordingly. Note how I left the actions and transitions out of it to keep it truly minimal.

Comment: What exactly is a `StateLogic` actually? In didn't see it in your codes ;)

Comment: It's in one of the paragraphs, without any of its members. It should've been in a code block with `IdleStateLogic`.

Comment: @madreflection thanks for the fiddle. I didn't doubt that the property could be assigned in code, but for some reason it's unassignable in the Unity inspector, that's the issue. Creating an instance of IdleStateLogic is nice and easy, but it breaks what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to get Actions, StateLogic, and Transitions all assigned in the inspector, so a unit's AI can be built from modular components. Also regarding the Enter() function in IdleStateLogic: it accepts UnitStateController instead of StateController since it needs to access a property specific to UnitStateController.

Comment: I don't know about the inspector but you'll have to test if `stateLogic` is an `IdleStateLogic` instance and then cast it to that type in order to call the non-virtual `Enter` method. That would defeat the purpose of the State Pattern -- at least that's what it looks like were going for here.

Comment: Yeah that definitely breaks the pattern. I don't see a good way around it. I could have StateLogic's Enter() function accept a params so its optional, but that's far from ideal. How can I get this pattern to work?

Comment: That's a very broad question. So far, you've only discussed the mechanism, which we've determined is "broken". Whether or not it is one, treat it like an XY problem. Step back from the mechanism and rethink the solution starting from the original goal. It might also help to take another look at the State pattern itself. You strayed from it a bit, and that might have been part of why it didn't work.

Comment: So from what I can tell there are two issues: 1) I can't expose stateLogic in the inspector to be assigned. And 2) IdleStateLogic's Enter() function breaks the pattern by accepting a subclass of StateController, rather than StateController itself. To me the first issue is more pressing. Is the solution to do a customer editor extension to expose the property, or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: I'm bowing out. I don't do Unity so that's above my pay grade.

Comment: Ah damn, well I appreciate the advice nonetheless. Thanks @madreflection

Comment: A custom editor would probably have the same issue .. I really don't see though why it shouldn't be assignable in the Inspector ... Could you describe better what exactly that means? Does it not allow to drop anything in the slot or is it not saved?

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign to `stateLogic` in the inspector because it is a property, not a field. Try this:

```
public class State : ScriptableObject
{
    public StateLogic stateLogic;
    public Action[] actions;
    public Transition[] transitions;
}
```

A consequence of this is that it also can't be virtual. That seems a bit over-engineered for your use case anyway, though.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried (I only attempted to make it a property as a last resort).